# WSOD on admin/modules/install

Tags: 7, wsod

I have a **clean** installation Drupal7.

In page **Modules -> Install new module -> Upload a module or theme archive to install** I select views-7.x-3.7.tar.gz (previously downloaded from drupal.org) and click button "install". Drupal redirect me to the same page, but with another design. I once again select file and click install. I get WSOD.

Important, that is a clean installation drupal, and I try purge and install it repeatedly and get same error. In php.ini:

```
max_execution_time = 180
max_input_time = 180
memory_limit = 256M
```

in index.php:

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', TRUE);
ini_set('display_startup_errors', TRUE);
```

in .htaccess i add "RewriteBase /", but this not solve problem

Before installation, I "chown" drupal folder to "www-data" (xubuntu start apache2 as this user), and dont create any folders - drupal create it himself.

this article cannot solve problem drupal.org/node/482956

HMP

upd:

/var/log/apache2/access.log - http://bpaste.net/show/261459/

/var/log/apache2/access.log - http://bpaste.net/show/261473/ (another version)

/var/log/apache2/error.log - http://bpaste.net/show/261480/

upd2:

now i create VirtualboxVM, and install drupal there. **Module succesfull installed**. How I can find, why on host-system module not installing? Which what settings may be different?

Comment: Did you check your server logs?

Comment: Yes. When i click install, "error.log" nothing logged, "access.log" recieve one record

Comment: Now, i paste it`s output

Comment: tail -f access.log: http://bpaste.net/show/261459/

  last line in log (POST query) I recieve `HTTP-500 Internal Server Error`. What does it mean?

Comment: Error 500 (Internal server error) means your site crashed. It may be caused by a PHP syntax error (unlikely if you're site is a clean install), an Apache configuration error, directory permissions settings, or something else. Usually, further clues should be in your Apache logs (make sure they exist and that www-data has permission to write to them).

Comment: I chmod a+x to access.log and error.log, repeat adding module and get this access.log - http://bpaste.net/show/261473/   HTTP-500 error disappeared but, WSOD remained.

Comment: tail -n 30 error.log http://bpaste.net/show/261480/

Comment: I think, problem in apache directives, but i dont know in which. But "RewriteBase /" not solve problem

Comment: now i create VirtualboxVM, and install drupal there. **Module succesfull installed**. How I can find, why on host-system module not installing? Which what settings may be different?

Comment: https://drupal.org/node/158043 - have you seen it, read it, and tried to apply it?

Comment: @Molot Yes, of course, also I read http://drupal.org/node/482956